Github action powershell exit codes and error action preferences
I am trying to get the latest tag from git in a Github Action workflow (runs-on: windows-2022).
      - name: Get the latest tag from Git
        shell: pwsh
        run: |
          try {
            $LATEST_TAG = git describe --tags --abbrev=0
          } catch {
            Write-Host "Failed to get the latest tag from Git. Setting LATEST_TAG to 'none'."
            $LATEST_TAG = "none"
          }
          echo "LATEST_TAG=$LATEST_TAG" >> $env:GITHUB_ENV  # Save latest tag to the environment file

The problem is that the git describe exits with an error code whenever there is no tag in history. This should not be a problem, because I encompass the code with a try/catch block.

This documentation https://docs.github.com/en/actions/writing-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#exit-codes-and-error-action-preference states that it is due to the $ErrorActionPreference that is set to stop by Github.
It seems I could bypass the code that is prepended and appended by Github to the script to avoid this behaviour, but I was not able to make it work properly.
How to avoid stopping the whole process if git describe returns an error?

You need to set shell i.e. shell: pwsh -File {0} or shell: powershell -Command "& '{0}'" as mentioned in the last point of under Exit codes and error action preference.

@Azeem, already tried it (before posting) and the result was exactly the same. It's like the try catch block doesn't catch anything

According to this documentation, you need to set $PSNativeCommandUseErrorActionPreference to $true if you want native commands like git to respect $ErrorActionPreference. By doing so your git command should produce an exception that is caught by your catch.

Commands of type native, like git, by default don't produce errors in the same way as PowerShell commands. A starting point when learning about the differences could be the documentation of $PSNativeCommandUseErrorActionPreference.
So if you want a native command to produce an error that you can catch with a try-catch statement, you can

Set $ErrorActionPreference to 'Stop'.
Set $PSNativeCommandUseErrorActionPreference to $true.

That should be sufficient if you opt out of the built-in shell according to the docs:

Users can always opt out by not using the built-in shell, and providing a custom shell option like: pwsh -File {0}, or powershell -Command "& '{0}'", depending on need.

If you stick with the built-in shell, you'll probably have to reset $LASTEXITCODE to 0 in your catch clause, since, according to the same docs:

... action statuses reflect the script's last exit code.

($LASTEXITCODE is set to the value that git describe exits with, which seems to be 1 when no tags exist, resulting in the GitHub Action failing.)

I can confirm the LASTEXITCODE solution works, I haven't tested the former solution yet
